# Как скомпилировать html разметку добавленный через v-html?

Tags: vue.js

> Я вставляю html разметку через v-html и у меня не срабатывает событие на нажатие по этому элементу, причину понял - это связано с тем, что у меня не скомпилирована то, что я вставляю. И такой вопрос как скомпилировать элемент, которую я вставляю через v-html?

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        msg: 'Hellow world',
        check: '',
        life: 0,
        inspan: []
    },
    mounted(){
        this.life = 3;
        for (var i=0; i<6; i++){
            this.inspan.push('<span class="block" id="'+i+'" v-on:click="inspect"></span>')
        } 
    },
    methods:{
        inspect: function(event){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    }
})


----------
## html ##

<body>
    <div id="app" class="content">
        <div class="section">
            <p>Количество жизни:{{life}}</p>
            <p>Запомните местоположение фигур</p>
            <div class="inp_section">
                <a v-for="sp in inspan" v-html="sp"></a>
            </div>
            <p>{{check}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Управляет HTML-содержимым элемента (`innerHTML`). Обратите внимание, что содержимое вставляется как обычный HTML — то есть не компилируется как шаблон Vue.
>
> —*[источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)*

---

`v-html` для того и сделан, чтобы Vue обрабатывал содержимое как строку. Вы же в точности наоборот хотите получить.

Используйте `<a v-for="..."  @click="inspect"`, либо создайте полноценный дочерний компонент, что предпочтительнее.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Модель с элементами.
    collection: [],
    // Остальные ваши данные.
    msg: 'Hellow world',
    check: '',
    life: 0,
  },
  // При монтировании экземпляра приложения,
  // получаем данные из вне, либо создаем на месте.
  mounted() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      // Добавляем в коллекцию объект.
      this.collection.push({
        id: i,
        title: `Item ${i}`
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inspect(event, index) {
      // Просто выбираем объект по переданному индексу.
      const item = this.collection[index];

      alert(item.id + ': ' + item.title);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app" class="content">
  <div class="section">
    <p>Количество жизни: {{ life }}</p>
    <p>Запомните местоположение фигур</p>
    <ul class="inp_section">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in collection" :key="item.id">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="inspect($event, index)">
          <span class="block">{{ item.title }}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{ check }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- <script src="main.js"></script> -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Как видно из примера, мы не добавляем в коллекцию готовые `html` куски, а добавляем объекты.

---

Директива `v-html` применяется (и не только) при создании WYSIWYG редакторов, когда используется атрибут [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

```
<div contenteditable="true" v-html="..."></div>
```

Comment: Мне надо знать id элемента на которую пользователь нажимал, а если я в тег <a> запишу событие @click, то не смогу взять id <span>. Может есть какие-то альтернативные варианты, когда можно скомпилировать и так же через v-html вставить?

Comment: Был бы очень благодарен если подсказали))

Comment: Нет оно у меня будет меняться, только я еще полностью не дописал - это был как тестовый вариант, чтоб хотя бы что-то заработала.

Comment: Могу вам отправить полностью проект, чтобы вы полностью вникли, то, что я хочу сделать

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам, теперь я понял предназначение v-html и как все таки правильно делать.Вы супер!!!